# Postcondition 'this.Interaction should not be null' exception while identifying a Contact

Tags: contact-facets, contact

Sitecore 9.3

I have an API endpoint and is being used to identify the contact. When it is being called through Sitecore application, it is working absolutely fine but it's failing with below exception while calling with **Postman** client.

```
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.EnsuresValidator`1.ThrowExceptionCore(String condition, String additionalMessage, ConstraintViolationType type)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.Throw.ValueShouldNotBeNull[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNull[T](ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.IdentifyAs(String source, String knownIdentifier)
```

Any pointer?

Comment: Are you identifying using an API call?

Comment: Yes. That api call have necessary information in its payload.

Comment: I believe what is happening is that the api call you are making doesn’t include the browser cookies. If you are using Fetch use “include security”.

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you please give some more details? Thanks

Comment: When you make an API call and you want Sitecore to do analytics stuff, you need to make the API call include all the cookies and such so Sitecore knows who you are. See here in the section "Sending a request with credentials included", https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We faced the same issue and raised Sitecore support ticket for the same and we get to know that if you try to hit from Postman, need to `remove user-agent from postman` headers like below -

https://www.screencast.com/t/K0BiMxHv

This was only happening on `Sitecore 9.3`, in Sitecore 9.0.2 it was working fine for us.

Also, I wrote a blog about this you can check [here](https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2020/08/04/postcondition-this-interaction-should-not-be-null-exception-while-identifying-a-contact/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably after for Postman is your cookie data. You need to grab your cookie data from an active Sitecore request and paste it into Postman. In the screenshot, the bottom frame is from by browser developer tools looking at the network call I am making to Sitecore.

[image]